# i am getting a null-pointer at resource.length() and i am not able to figure it out why? even though the the file has data

Tags: java

```
class WordCount
{
    String resource;
    void read () throws IOException
    {
         File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\read.txt");  
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
         while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null)
         {
                 resource.trim();
         }
         System.out.println(resource.length());
         br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: We know from the loop condition that `resource` will always be non-null inside the loop, so `resouce.trim()`can't be the error.  The same loop condition also guarantees that`resource==null` when the loop is finished.  And what's right after the loop? Yep, `System.out.println(resource.length())`. KABOOM!  Did you mean to put that `println` _inside_ the loop?

Comment: Your file always have a data in your code. your resource variable data is changing. 
what are actually trying to achieve using 

      System.out.println(resource.length());

Answer (score 1):

Here you are assigning null at final step of loop:

```
while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null)
```